# Signalr hub get caller client from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

How can i get the caller client (the client which is requesting the current action) from controller.

something like the following:

```
  public class ChatController : EntityController
  {
      public void RegisterClientAsAvailable()
      {
          var hub=Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();

          var callingClient = hub.Clients.Caller;

//And I want to pass additional parameters(which the client doesnt know about them) from `EntityController (base)` to this method:

          hub.RegisterClient(base.UserId,Session["something"],callingClient);
          //OR:
          hub.SayHelloToClient(base.UserId,Session["something"],callingClient);
      }
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? CallerContext is only available on your hub class, so you if you want to track client connections, the hub is the right place to start. Connections come and go and your mvc controller would not get called again, only your hub knows about added or removed connections. But it's not clear what you want to do. Maybe post more code.

Comment: @thomaswr:just added more lines